Assessing heteroscedasticity in residuals vs. fitted values graph
I am running a mixed model regression with 3 levels (schools, groups and students). I applied robust standard errors with the R function coef_test(modelo6b, vcov = "CR2") and some of the variables that were previously significant turned out to be insignificant.
Thus, I believe there might be heteroscedasticity in the model.
I wanted to check if there is any kind of heteroscedasticity in the model, so I produced the residuals vs. fitted values dispersion graph. Do you think that there is any sign of heteroscedasticity here? It doesn't seem like it for me. Why would I then get considerably different CI when applying robust standard errors?


could you please add for us a few of your standard errors vs robust standard errors? To see what you mean by "considerably different CIs"

At a first glance, the plot doesn't look problematic. However, there is substantial overplotting. Could you maybe bin the fitted values and create histograms for the bins?

As I guess you know, there are various flavours of robust standard errors. Most are an attempt to give more honest SEs given more than heteroscedasticity.  For your own work and for the benefit of people not using R, it's important to be clear on precisely what CR2 claims to do.

For low and high fitted values, there are far fewer points. That's fine but it is difficult to assess variance across bands with very many values and with very few values. Simple things you can do are (1) plot absolute values, so fold the bottom half of the graph over the top  (2) smooth absolute values with any scatterplot smoother of your choice.

For better visualizations, try plotting the squared or absolute residuals vs. Fitted, then overlay the Lowess fit.

Does this answer your question? Heteroscedasticity in Linear Regression I think the techniques explained in the linked post are highly relevant and applicable here.
